# Use space bar to input a value in an excel cell

Tags: cells

Could someone help me with a macro code/formula to enable space bar to input a value in a cell? For e.g., if I hit space bar when I am on a cell, I would like to print "x" in it. Is it possible?

Comment: The key combination for macro is `ctrl+<key>`. I think you can't use a key like space to get something done. It violates the basics of shortcuts. 'Ctrl+S` -> Save; `Ctrl+A`-> Select all; It is always a two key combination if you see.....

Comment: Perhaps you can use data validation to suppply a pulldown list with an `"x"` in it. Tthe user clicks the cell and a popup with x comes up. They can then click that to enter the x in it, and alternatively another space to clear the cell again. the list would be `"x";""`.

Comment: Another option is to use form controls. The checkbox there will react to the space, but you cannot save these changes to the file. if you just need to print what you have made, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro is very simple, something like:

```
Sub Makro1()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "x"
End Sub
```

The only one problem is, like [Prasanna](https://superuser.com/users/345527/prasanna) mentioned, the short cut for it.
You cann't use the **TAB**, only the key combination `ctrl+<key>` is allowed.